# pm2 how to avoid schedule cron lock in nestjs

Tags: cron, nestjs, locking, schedule

I use `pm2` to run the service. I have a total of 2 clusters.

And I created a `schedule job` in `nestjs` and executed the schedule,
but both clusters ran schedule and the database was locked.

how can i avoid this?

below is my ecosystem.js

```js
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {

      name: 'my_app',
      script: 'dist/main.js',
      instances: 0,
      exec_mode: 'cluster',
      listen_timeout: 10000,
      kill_timeout: 1000,
    },
  ],
};
```

Answer (score -1):

i can use `process.env.pm_id`

1. pm2 list
2. check my pm_id list
3. 

```js
@Cron('* * * * ... ')
myCron(){
if(process.env.pm_id === '0') {
 ...
}
}
```

Comment: Won't work if the pm2 id change